# Use cmd in Java to find PID of process running on port 80 exactly

Tags: java, cmd, pid, findstr

Requirement: Get the PID of the process running on Port 80.

I have the following cmd command (in Java) which is supposed to show the current process running on port 80:

```
String cmd = "cmd /c netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0:80
```

Executing this command works just fine with one downside. It also returns processes that run on port `8080` for example.

The issue is obviously that the `findstr` command is looking for the substring `0.0.80` which also fits i.e.: `0.0.8080`.
I have been looking around now trying to match on a space or tabulator like findstr `0.0.80`(space) or `0.0.80\t` (By escaping).

How can I inculde spaces and tabulators in the search string?

**EDIT: I went ahead with PalBGD's proposed solution and do the final parsing in Java now.**

Comment: You could parse the command manually in java instead of using `findstr`, if that's an option.

Comment: Im thinking about that as a last resort, yeah! Thats definetly a good option!

Comment: What about `findstr "0.0:80 "` (with a space before the second `"`)

Comment: Putting the search string in double quotes didn't work. I went ahead with PalBGD's proposed solution and do the final parsing in Java now. Thanks for your comment anyway!

Comment: Type `Findstr /?` . `Findstr /c:"0.0.80"`